# How to check the current platform of Android OS?

Tags: android-x86, compatibility, emulators

There are 4 common platform such as: ARM, ARM64, x86 and x86_64 on which Android can run.

**How can I check which platform I'm on within Android OS?** So I can check whether my app is compatible with it or not.

I'm using different emulators (BlueStacks on Mac, Genymotion on Demand, etc.), so I'd like to check basically which platform they're exactly emulating, because some apps works for me on BlueStacks, but not on Genymotion.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you have [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) set up, it's a one-liner at the shell prompt:

```
$ adb shell "getprop ro.product.cpu.abi"
arm64-v8a
```

In this example, the device asked answered that it has a 64bit ARM V8a CPU (second line).

Note: You can also run the quoted command in a terminal emulator running on the device / emulator. In there, it's just `getprop ro.product.cpu.abi`.

Answer (score 6):

[CPU -Z](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cpuid.cpu_z) is a versatile app that gives you SoC information apart from some other apps

[image]

From app description on play store